# Raycaster inside box with BackSide material doesn't work

Tags: three.js, box, raycasting

I am doing a project on Tree.js (NICE lib!).

I have a problem. The rayCaster does not work when the ray is made inside the box.

I have an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/manumid/7sqd6xzs/7/ 
(extracted from https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3969).

The box materials are THREE.BackSide, and I am using MultiMaterial because I need to represent a room with different textures. The material is made like this:

```
var materials = [
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xff0000,
                                 side:THREE.BackSide}), // Right
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x00ff00,
                                 side:THREE.BackSide}), // Left
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x0000ff,
                                 side:THREE.BackSide}), // Top
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x222222, 
                                 side:THREE.BackSide}), // Bottom
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xffff00, 
                                 side:THREE.BackSide}), // Back
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x00ffff, 
                                 side:THREE.BackSide}), // Front
];

var cubeSidesMaterial = new THREE.MultiMaterial(materials);
var roomGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(4, 4, 4);

var newRoom = new THREE.Mesh(roomGeometry, cubeSidesMaterial);
```

When the ray is made from outside, there is intersection, but against the external faces of the box (can it be a bug? The external faces have no textures!). This can be seen with the distance of the intersection.

Anyway, as a temporal solution, I can make the room with individual Planes joined on a Group.

Thank you!

Comment: `Raycaster` does not support `MultiMaterial` in three.js r.84. If you would like to file a three.js bug report with a link to your fiddle, that would be great.